# Copy file in windows 7 using Tcl command

Tags: tcl

How can use Tcl command in windows-7 ? I want to copy one file to other locaiton using a .bat file.

Comment: `.bat` files are executed using the Windows command shell (`cmd.exe`), which is commonly known as the Windows command prompt. So what your question has to do with Tcl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can use Tcl command in windows-7 ?

Windows (of all versions) has never come with a Tcl interpreter pre-installed, By far the simplest way is to get a copy of [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl) installed.

Once you've got that installed, either run it interactively and just type your Tcl command in at the prompt, or use a text editor (like Notepad) to make a file (conventionally with extension `.tcl`) that contains the command or commands to execute; you'll probably be able to make the file run by just double-clicking on it.

> I want to copy one file to other locaiton using a .bat file.

That's not really got much to do with Tcl. With Tcl, you would use:

```
file copy {C:\Where\To\Copy\From.txt} {C:\Where\To\Copy.to}
```

Note, we've put the filenames in `{`curly braces`}` here so that we can use backslashes; if we weren't doing that, we'd need to use double-backslashes instead (`\\`) or forward slashes (`/`).

The alternative, if you're really wanting to use a `.bat` file, is to look up what the cmd.exe commands `COPY` and (less likely) `XCOPY` do. But that's not a Tcl question.